# Missing dependency roscpp?

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"
[rosbuild] Building package veltrobot_movement
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/cturtle/ros/bin/rospack deps-manifests veltrobot_movement
[rospack] couldn't find dependency [roscpp] of [veltrobot_movement]
[rospack] missing dependency
"
How can I fix this?

http://www.ros.org/wiki/cturtle/Installation/Ubuntu I used this tutorial to install.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9139/missing-dependency-roscpp?/) by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2011-02-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on 2011-02-20**:
^ Restarted terminal and got. However when trying to build the veltrobot, now I'm getting missing dependency openni. When i run ~/ni/setup.sh , I get the roscpp error but not the openni error.

**Comment by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on 2011-02-20**:
[rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['roscpp']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/geniusgeeko/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110220-212109
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['roscpp'] to:
['roscpp']
[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .
executing this script:
set -o errexit
#No Packages to install
[ rosmake ] rosdep successfully installed all system dependencies
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 8 packages with 0 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/geniusgeeko/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110220-212109

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-02-20**:
Can you include the output of 'rosmake --rosdep-install roscpp'?

**Comment by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on 2011-02-20**:
"rosmake veltrobot_teleop veltrobot_movement robot_state_publisher rviz"
http://www.ros.org/wiki/cturtle/Installation/Ubuntu I used that tutorial to install.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-02-20**:
Can you list the exact command you are trying to use to build veltrobot_movement?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-02-20**:
How did you install ROS? Debs? Did you setup your .bashrc properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Conflicting packages... the problem was that when the terminal started it would cturtle/setup.bash then ~/ni/setup.sh the setup.sh would set the ROSROOT to the unstable and get rid of the veltrop packet list from the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. When adding the veltrop package to the PATH it would rid of the OPENNI package path. When running the ~/ni/setup.sh it would bring me to the unstable which would render to a roscpp due to conflicting paths. Thanks for the help.

---

Originally posted by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) with karma: 299 on 2011-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0